# make the search function on the app bar disappear

Tags: android, kotlin, search

I have an appbar that contains a search, I want to make it appear only in a fragment, not in all as it is happening now. How would I change his visibility?

Main Activity where is it implemented

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private lateinit var toggle: ActionBarDrawerToggle
private val controlador by lazy {
    findNavController(R.id.pokemons_activity_nav_host)
}

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity)
    configNavControler()
    configDrawer()

}


private fun configDrawer() {
    toggle = ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout as DrawerLayout?, R.string.open, 
R.string.close)
    (drawerLayout as DrawerLayout?)?.addDrawerListener(toggle)
    toggle.syncState()

    supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)


}

override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    if(toggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)){
        return true
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
}


private fun configNavControler() {
    val navView: BottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.main_activity_bottom_navigation)
    val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager
        .findFragmentById(R.id.pokemons_activity_nav_host) as NavHostFragment
    val navController = navHostFragment.navController

    navView.setupWithNavController(navController)

    configNavView(navController, navView)   // configura para ver se o Nav View aparece ou nao
}

private fun configNavView(
    navController: NavController,
    navView: BottomNavigationView

) {
    // pega o id do fragment e compara,se for igual, faz as atribuições necessárias (aparecer ou 
desaparecer Nav View)
    navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener { controller, destination, arguments ->
        if (destination.id == R.id.entrada_graph) {
            navView.visibility = View.GONE

        } else {
            navView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        }

    }
}

override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {

    val inflater = menuInflater
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.search_menu, menu)

    val manager = getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE) as SearchManager
    val searchItem = menu?.findItem(R.id.action_search)
    val searchView = searchItem?.actionView as SearchView

    searchView.setSearchableInfo(manager.getSearchableInfo(componentName))

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(object : SearchView.OnQueryTextListener{
        override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String?): Boolean {
            searchView.clearFocus()
            searchView.setQuery("", false)
            searchItem.collapseActionView()

            Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Carregando $query", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            return true
        }

        override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String?): Boolean {
            return false
        }

    })
    return true
  }
}
```

I want to make it appear in only one fragment, I tried to implement the same as my BottomNavigation but I couldn't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**KOTLIN**

I will show you how to set it up.
You need to understand that you can hide the `SearchView` when inflating your `Fragment`.
Define your `SearchView` public above `onCreate`:

```
val searchItem = menu?.findItem(R.id.action_search)
val searchView = searchItem?.actionView as SearchView
```

and in your `onCreateOptionsMenu` you can hide the `SearchView` with:

```
searchView.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
```

or if you want it to be shown:

```
searchView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
```

**Summary:**
You need to make `public static` variables to access everywhere (here your `SearchView`), then you set in your executing method wether the `SearchView` is `VISIBLE` for this `Fragment`/`Activity` or not. (inflating part in your class, where the action happen.)

**JAVA**

I give you a better example for that in `JAVA`:

Above your `onCreate` method as told before:

```
...

public static SearchView searchView; //Defining SearchView

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

and the mentioned executing part in your `OnClickListener` or `OnCreateOptionMenu`:

```
 button_inflating_other_fragment.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ...
            searchView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); //Here example OnClickListener
            ...
                return;
            }
```

**CONCLUSION:**

So as you can see you can specify with a few lines of code, wether the `SearchView` is `set` or not. I guess you will set that up correctly, Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

If you are in fragment and don't want to show app bar any menu then set

```
setHasOptionsMenu(false)
```

And if you need to show any then set in onCreate() method

```
setHasOptionsMenu(true)
```

After that you have to hide menu item and show item with this method:

```
@Override
  public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
  super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
  menu.findItem(R.id.menu_open).setVisible(false);
  menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search).setVisible(true);
}
```

That's it.